# ubuntu 10.04 xen default version

Tags: 10.04, xen

What is the default xen version from ubuntu 10.04?
The idea is that I need an ubuntu version where I can install with no problems xen 3.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [version 3.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/xen-hypervisor-3.3) from the Universe repository.